# Best reverse compatible approach to nullifying value in hidden field using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know the best reverse compatible approach to nullifying the value property in a hidden field using JQuery.

Thanks!

Note:

```
$('#MyHiddenField').val('');
```

is not good enough.

I need a good old fasioned null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The `value` property always holds a string. If you assign anything to it besides a string, it will be converted to a string.

That is because the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) interface's `value` property is of type `DOMString`. Independently of being a `hidden` input or not, the input element interface forces any value set to the `input`'s `value` property to be of type `string`, otherwise it'd render input elements unusable to the end-user - this is the purpose of input elements after all. Also it'd be impossible to make a regular `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request if the input values weren't strings.

You may be looking for something else than a hidden input, but what you can do without major changes in your code is simply checking if the value is an empty string before using it and assigning it to `null`:

```
var v = $('#MyHiddenField').val();
if (v === '') v = null;
//use v as null in your code now
```

And if you need it for posting to server-side, the operation is the same. Post it as an empty string then check if the posted data is an empty string and assign it to `null`.

Comment: exactly what i needed, great job!